# How to initialize async view model and how to handle exceptions in the dependency injection service?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a view model that needs to populate some collections with data from databases. This collections are like a list of provinces and, list of type of VAT and some another data like this.

My view model is something like that:

```
public clase MyViewModel
{
    //Just some service that is injected.
    private readonly ISomeService _someSerive;

    public MyViewModel(ISomeService paramSomeService)
    {
        public ObservableCOllection<Country> Countries = new ObservableCOllection<Country>();

        public ObservableCOllection<VAT> VATs = new ObservableCOllection<VAT>();

        // other properties and methods
    }
}
```

The constructor can't be async, and how I am using dependency injection, if I am not wrong, it is recommended that all the logic of creation of objects should to be done in the dependency injection service.

So I follow this documentation: [documentation of dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#async-di-factories-can-cause-deadlocks)

I am trying to instantiate `MyViewModel` like this:

```
// Service that provide access to database
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();

services.AddTransient<MyViewModel>(async myServiceProvider =>
{
    IMyService myService = myServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();

    List<VAT> myVats = await myService.GetTypesOfVatAsync();
    List<Country> myCountries = await myService.GetCountriesAsync();

    return myViewModel(myVats, myCountries);
});
```

Is this the correct way to do it? If it is, how should I handle the exceptions, for example because I can't connect to the server in the async methods?

There is another better solutions to instantiate the view model, when a view model needs some data from the database?

Thanks

Comment: In the vast majority of times, some including me will say always, it is not a good practice to execute async\await or any type of asynchronous actions inside a constructor. The creation of an object should be be dependent on io result. It will be better to return an object and the call that want the result will do the await when needs to.

Comment: When you talk about it is better to return a then call what I want, do you mean to use a factory to create the object and then call an async initialize method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I am not wrong, it is recommended that all the logic of creation of objetcs should to be done in the dependency injection service.

I'm afraid you are wrong, because best practice is to keep object composition (the creation of components with their dependencies) and retrieval of data separated. For more information read the following articles:

- [Injection Constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/)
- [Dependency Injection Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/)

In general, I advice developers to keep their components stateless whenever possible. In other words, besides storing incoming dependencies in private fields, store no runtime data in them. This advice, of course, goes completely against the whole idea of the concept of View Models in MVVM. View Models are inherently stateful. In the MVVM applications I currently maintain, we separate view model composition and initialization using an extra 'initialize' method on the view model. In essence, this looks like this:

```cs
public sealed class MyViewModel : IViewModel<MyData>
{
    //Just some service that is injected.
    private readonly IQueryProcessor queries;

    public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<VAT> VATs { get; }
    public MyData Data { get; }

    public MyViewModel(IQueryProcessor queries)
    {
        this.queries = queries;
    }

    public async Task Initialize(MyData data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.Countries = await this.queries.Execute(new GetCountries());
        this.VATs = await this.queries.Execute(new GetVATs());
    }
}
```

Comment: And when or who calls the initialize method?

Comment: It depends. In our case the `MyData` is usually a certain entity, e.g. `Person` and that person is already retrieved in another view model. Then the user presses the `EditPerson` button (which invokes the `EditPerson` method) and that person will cause the view model to be resolved, the view to be shown, and `Initialize` to be called on the view model. In our case, however, to decouple the view models, there's an abstraction in between them.